# Running Repast with Drools

Tags: java, drools, zombie-process, repast-simphony

I am trying to run the Repast zombie example with Drools but I got same errors at run time.
I created the zombie example and added all Drools jar-files into the class path. But when I call the newKnowledgeBuilder() function of the KnowledgeBuilderFactory:

> KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder =
>   KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();

I get this exception:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/drools/builder/KnowledgeBuilderFactory

Has anyone experience in running Repast with Drools?

Answer (score 0):

Check your classpath. You missed drools jar on it.